# Trying to make a dropdown on hover with jQuery in Magento

Tags: jquery, magento, drop-down-menu, hover

I am trying to create a dropdown menu on the navigation bar in Magento.
As you will see in my code all dropdown menu's collapse when i hover over one of the list items. But i can't figure out how to make only the correct one appear without making a hover function for each li and that seems like a non-effective way to reach my goal.

So i was hoping you guys could help me out :)

This is what i have so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="navigation-bar">
<ul class="mainLevel">
    <li class="navLink mainCategory1"><a href="http://fabriqmagento.development.cream.nl/new-in.html" class="level-top"><span>New in</span></a></li>
    <li class="listSeperator">|</li>
    <li class="navLink mainCategory2"><a href="http://fabriqmagento.development.cream.nl/merken.html" class="level-top"><span>Merken</span></a>
        <ul class="level0">
            <li class="navLink mainCategory1"><a href="http://fabriqmagento.development.cream.nl/merken/diesel.html"><span>Diesel</span></a></li>
            <li class="listSeperator"></li>
            <li class="navLink mainCategory2"><a href="http://fabriqmagento.development.cream.nl/merken/becksondergaard.html"><span>Becksondergaard</span></a></li>
            <li class="listSeperator"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="listSeperator">|</li>
    <li class="navLink mainCategory3"><a href="http://fabriqmagento.development.cream.nl/categorie.html" class="level-top"><span>Categorie</span></a></li>
    <li class="listSeperator">|</li>
    <li class="navLink mainCategory4"><a href="http://fabriqmagento.development.cream.nl/tassen.html" class="level-top"><span>Tassen</span></a></li>
    <li class="listSeperator">|</li>
    <li class="navLink mainCategory5"><a href="http://fabriqmagento.development.cream.nl/accessoires.html" class="level-top"><span>Accessoires</span></a></li>
    <li class="listSeperator">|</li>
    <li class="navLink mainCategory6"><a href="http://fabriqmagento.development.cream.nl/jeans.html" class="level-top"><span>Jeans</span></a></li>
    <li class="listSeperator">|</li>
    <li class="navLink mainCategory7"><a href="http://fabriqmagento.development.cream.nl/outlet.html" class="level-top"><span>Outlet</span></a></li>
    <li class="listSeperator">|</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```
ul.level0{ display:none;}
```

jQuery:

```
(function(window, $, undefined) {

    jQuery(function(){
        $('li.navLink').hover(function(){
            $('ul.level0').show();
        }, function(){
            $('ul.level0').hide();
        })
    });

})(window, jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just needed a couple of changes to the script...

http://jsfiddle.net/8846T/

```
(function($) {

    jQuery(function(){
        $('li.navLink').hover(function(){
            $('ul.level0').hide();
            $(this).find('ul.level0').show();
        }, function(){
            $('ul.level0').hide();
        })
    });

})(jQuery);
```

I made it hide all level0 ul elements on hover, and then show the child level0 ul element of the hovered li.

I also removed a little bit of code from your function call as it was not needed :)